# A large set of low dimensional vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^L$, which sums of any small subset do not cancel.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, coding-theory

Fix a number $n$ and $L=O(\log n)$. Let  $S=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a set of vectors where $v_i\in \mathbb{F}_2^L$.

We say that $S$ is "$\alpha$-good" iff for any nonempty subset  $T \subset S$ where $|T|\le \alpha$,
$$\sum_{s\in T }s\neq0.$$

It is easy to show the existence of a $\alpha$-good set $S$, for any $\alpha<L$, by choosing $s_i$ uniformly randomly, and then use the union bound.

My question is

- does it exist an $\alpha$-good set $S$, where $\alpha\ge L$ ?
- does the definition of "$\alpha$-good" have any other name ? or similar concept ?

Comment: Any subset of $\alpha$ elements of an $\alpha$-good set is linearly dependent over $\Bbb{F}_2$, so this implies that the answer to your first question is negative. BTW, what's the reason for using a quotient of the polynomial ring? For the purposes of this question the elements are just vectors in $\Bbb{F}_2^L$!? As to the second question: there may be a combinatorial/coding theoretical related concept, but I can't wrap my head around it now :-)

Comment: *I suppose that in the definition of $\alpha$-good you want $0<|T|\leq\alpha$, because $\sum_{s\in\varnothing}s=0$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Your first argument holds for $\alpha>L$, but not for $\alpha=L$: Any basis of $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^L)$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$ is a subset of $L$ elements that is $L$-good. In fact, you can add the sum of all basis elements to this set to get a subset of $L+1$ elements that is $L$-good, and that's as far as it goes.

Comment: @Servaes Thank you. I tried to fix my mistake.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. I change it to $\mathbb{F}_2^L$ now.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $L=O(\log n)$ in this context. I first read it as 'big-O' notation, but then all this says is that $L$ is constant because $\log n$ is constant, as $n$ is a fixed integer. But of course $L$ must be a fixed integer for $\Bbb{F}_2^L$ to make sense, making $L=O(\log n)$ redundant. Would you care to explain please?

Comment: @Servaes Sorry,  I want to say that $L \le c\cdot \log n$ for some fixed $c$.

Comment: I understand, thank you.